# Python List Index Out Of Range in For loop

Tags: python, list, indexing

Please I have no clue what's happening...

```
import random
o = 0
p = 5
n = 5
z = -1
y = -1
a = ["x" * n]
b = [7,7,1,8,2]

while o != p:
     for x in range(n):
         z += 1
         y += 1
         while a[z] != b[y]
              a[z] = random.randint(0,9)
         y += 1
         print(str(b[0:y])
         y -= 1
         o += 1
```

I hope everything is understandable. My code is kinda messy and gets polished so I changed the variables. The error is here ALWAYS when the 2nd PRINT HAPPENS, only and always when the b is printed 2nd times no matter what the n is except n = 1:

```
while a[z] != b[y]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Try opening a Python interactive console window, and type `["x" * 5]` to see what you get. That should explain it.

Comment: I'd be surprised you didn't get a syntax error before the index out of range error occurs for the second while loop.

Comment: Oh yeah I got ["xxxxx"] I thought I'd get ["x","x","x","x","x"] Thank you dude I'll check if the code works now

Comment: @Aspect: a = ["x" * n] becomes ['xxxxx'] which is a single element array, but you are trying to iterate till 5th element, hence you are getting out of bounds exception

Comment: Ok wait so how do I make it  ["x","x","x","x","x"] instead of ["xxxxx"]. it's really important for me to mulitply it by the variable (n) e.g a = [......... * n]

Comment: Oh you're already very close....Try creating a list of a single element, and then "multiply" that list... :)

Comment: So many syntax errors. Missing `:` after `while`. Missing `)` after `print(str...`

Comment: Well... It's still not working did like this: a = ["z"] and then a * n. Still an index out of range error in the same line and after 2nd print... I don't know what's going on.. :c Those syntax errors are just here. My code is clear just this error was writing a question here as fast as I could so thats why

Comment: Look at the answer I wrote below. I didn't get any `index out of range error`. I have updated the answer with the output I get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `a = ["x" * n]` by `a = ["x"] * n` and it should work, provided you get rid of all syntax errors. The following is the output.

```
[7]
[7, 7]
[7, 7, 1]
[7, 7, 1, 8]
[7, 7, 1, 8, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks <3 Finally... Understood.